# Ubuntu server 12.04 can't connect home wireless network

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, server, router

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 (server) without GUI.

I have Netgear wireless card ( model:wg311v3 ) that i have installed it through *ndiswrapper* driver wrapper to work with windows driver.

I don't have dchp installed ( i want to have static ip so i can use router's port forwarding ).

I don't have network-manager installed.

I have googled a lot and haven't manage to connect to my home wireless network ( with encryption WPA/WPA2 PSK ). I am very confused of all the different approaches.

I am not experienced linux user working with terminal ( no GUI installed ) but i know the basics so as to understand what you are writing.

Can anyone explain me the steps to connect to my wireless router and gain access to the internet?

How do i set the ip addresses and everything? just a simple guide.

How do i set it up so as to work with **WPA** encryption?

I have tried a lot before posting this question but i haven't manage it to work and now i am very confused and need to start from the beginning.

Thank you

Comment: anyone to provide a link with a good tutorial at least?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem with wireless access when I entered the Linux world a few months ago.

I found what seems to be a solution on the forum page listed below. What worked for me was to run the two "sudo" statements from the terminal (I don't know exactly what they do, but it worked):

> sudo modprobe -r iwlagn
>
> sudo modprobe iwlagn bt_coex_active=0
>
> ----- To make the change permanent:
>
> gsku gedit /etc/modprobe.d/iwl.conf
>
> ----- Copy/paste this line into the new file:
>
> options iwlagn bt_coex_active=0

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/876147

...I tried to follow the directions and "make the change permanent", but it didn't seem to work for me. So I just run the two "sudo" statements via a bash file every time I restart my computer...

(Sorry, I can't post anything intelligent about your WPA or the IP questions)

I hope that helps...